# Having 2 separate close buttons for 2 JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a small application, with a JMenuBar, now, I got a menuitem, which is a store, which opens a new JFrame. When I click the button, a new JFrame appears, all good. But, when I click the close button of my Store JFrame, I don't want my main JFrame to close. If I press the store-close-button now, it will close down both the main JFrame, and the Store JFrame, any help on making like, 2 separate close buttons for these 2 JFrames? Code for main JFrame:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    //Create new JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("MrStan");
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    //Set location of JFrame
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = (int) dim.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = (int) dim.getHeight();
    frame.setLocation(screenWidth / 2 - 200, screenHeight / 2 - 200);

    //Set ContentPane to JPanel
    MrStan panel = new MrStan();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    //Make the user not be able to resize
    frame.setResizable(false);

    //Make the JFrame visible
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

My store JFrame:

```
    public MrStanStore(){   
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setTitle("Store");
    frame2.setSize(300, 200);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    //Set location of JFrame
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = (int) dim.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = (int) dim.getHeight();
    frame2.setLocation(screenWidth / 2 - 200, screenHeight / 2 - 200);

    //Make the user not be able to resize
    frame2.setResizable(false);

    //Make the JFrame visible
    frame2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without code.  There are too may possibilities to make a guess.

Comment: OK, but at this point we still don't see the code for them menuitem in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 2 JFrames. Generally applications should have a single JFrame and then you use JDialogs for support windows. JDialogs to not support exiting the VM when then are closed so this will not be an issue.

If you do use a JFrame then you should use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE. Then when the last frame is closed the VM will exit automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you previously called `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation` to something like `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`? Try setting it to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` and you can handle the close event any way you want.

Comment: Well, I do want to close it down, I just don't want to close down the whole program.

Comment: Set it to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` perhaps.